# Fix the plot range in Manipulate a list density plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I am trying to see the time evolution of a scalar field using `Manipulate` on `ListDensityPlot`. 
However, even if I fix the range using `PlotRange`, the legend keeps changing from frame to frame. Note that this does not happen if I use `Manipulate` with `ListPlot`.
Here's the code:

```
Manipulate[
 ListDensityPlot[
  Flatten[Table[{(1 + y[[1 + (i - 1)]]) Cos[\[Theta]], (1 + 
        y[[1 + (i - 1)]]) Sin[\[Theta]], 
     Evaluate[(Subscript[f, 1 + (i - 1)][t] /. sol[[1, 2 + i]])]}, {i,
      1, 200, 1}, {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi, 0.05 Pi}], 1], 
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}, {0, 1}}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, Below]], {t, 0, 5000*2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

I believe this is probably a simple thing I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `sol`?${}$

Comment: Sol is an interpolation function that is the solution coming from an NDSolve